# Can you display a image stored on a web server using ImageView

Tags: android, imageview

If I have some images stored on my server, can they be displayed using the imagevue? I was thinking about using small WebVues, but see this as a lot of over head.  The reason is that I want the images t chnage, without having to update my app
- Ted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just have a background task that downloads the image from the web server, caches it to the file system, and displays it from there. If it updates periodically, you can poll every so often for changes.